# Google play console rejects production release reviewing an old version

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

I have published a new version of production with an apk file. But Play Store Console Keep rejecting with an old version review. The old version hasn't even been released for production. Maybe it has released for a testing. The reason was the following.

- About the User Generated Content (UGC) policy

The last version has rejected with the above reason. But after creating another release, it was completed. And now, The rejection occurred again for the same reason.

The question is why Google keep reviewing older version and reject the release again that has completed.

- The attached screenshot by Google Play Console was the exactly same.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google also reviews APKs/AABs that are published in testing tracks. Make sure the artifacts published in all your tracks are also compliant (by uploading new compliant versions in those tracks as well).